# Function Growth Proof

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove:
$\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq n_0 \implies an \leq 2^n$

The hints are:

- Use induction on $n$
- it’s easier if you don’t try to find the smallest possible $n_0$

I don't know where to start other than setting up the induction. When it comes to the proof, I am stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Additional hints:

$a(n+1) = an + a\cdot 1$

Meanwhile $2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n = 2^n + 2^n$

We should be able to convince ourselves that $a\leq an$.  Supposing that we were able to compare $an$ and $2^n$, can we use this knowledge to compare $a(n+1)$ and $2^{n+1}$?

---

As far as "don't try to find the smallest possible $n_0$" that is very good advice.  Following that advice, let's consider what happens if we take $n_0$ to be $\lceil a\rceil$ itself.  Then how does $an_0$ compare to $2^{n_0}$?

> Is it true that $n^2\leq 2^n$ for any positive integer $n$ greater than $3$?  If you don't know that this is true already, then perhaps try proving this by induction as well.

---

Full answer:  Try to finish the problem on your own before looking here.

We wish to prove that for any $a\in \Bbb R^+$ there exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $an\leq 2^n$.

> Claim: Letting $n_0 = \max(\lceil a\rceil,4)$ suffices.

$~$

> Base case: We have $an_0 \leq n_0^2$. Remembering that $n^2\leq 2^n$ for all positive integers $n$ greater than $3$ (*proof left to reader*) it follows that $n_0^2\leq 2^{n_0}$ and thus $an_0\leq 2^{n_0}$.

$~$

> Inductive step: Supposing as our induction hypothesis that $an\leq 2^n$ is true for some particular value of $n$, we recognize that $a(n+1) = an + a \leq an + an$ which by applying our induction hypothesis to each of these terms is less than $2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$

Comment: but... $3^2>2^3$.

Comment: "but .... $3^2 > 2^3$".   what does that have to do with anything? If $a=3$ then $n_0$ can not be $3$.  So.... $n_0$ is bigger than $3$.

Comment: @Poypoyan I had forgotten about that case, but it is easily fixed (*and the fix should have been apparent to you as well*).

Comment: How did you exactly find $n_0$?

Comment: @Zexion12 I recognized that $n^2\leq 2^n$ is a very common and commonly used inequality (*so long as as pointed out $n>3$*) and tried to use that.  No other reason.  There are surely far far far better choices for $n_0$ that provide tighter bounds, but as pointed out in the question there is no reason to bend over backwards to find one of the tighter bounds.